# can i include functions.php of the parent theme

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a subtheme in wordpress. I just need to know is it possible to include the functions.php of the parent theme so that I need not to copy the functions that are already defined in parent theme and simply define new functions or overide existing if required.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Child Themes page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Using_functions.php):

> Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not
>   override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in
>   addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded
>   right before the parent’s file.)

So, you don't need to redefine anything. You can't usually override the original functions, though, since your `functions.php` is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a fresh blank functions.php file and place it in your child-theme folder. Then you can add all your own custom functions. All of the parent theme functions will automatically be built into your child theme. No need to carry them over. Start Fresh and Clean!